# Airflow File Sensor for sensing files on my local drive

Tags: airflow

does anybody have any idea on FileSensor ? I came through it while i was researching on sensing files on my local directory. The code is as follows:

```
  task= FileSensor(
    task_id="senseFile"
    filepath="etc/hosts",
    fs_conn_id='fs_local',
   _hook=self.hook,
    dag=self.dag,)
```

I have also set my conn_id and conn type as File (path) and gave the {'path':'mypath'} but even though i set a non existing path or if the file isnt there in the specified path, the task is completed and the dag is successful. The FileSensor doesnt seem to sense files at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the community contributed FileSenor a little bit underwhelming so wrote my own.

I got it working for files locally to where the server/scheduler was running however ran into problems when using network paths.

The trick for network paths I found was to mount the network drive to my Linux Box.

This is my DAG used to sensor_task >> proccess_task >> archive_task >> trigger rerun

Note: We use variables (sourcePath, filePattern & archivePath) entered via the WebGUI

```
    from airflow import DAG
    from airflow.operators import PythonOperator, OmegaFileSensor, ArchiveFileOperator, TriggerDagRunOperator
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta
    from airflow.models import Variable

    default_args = {
        'owner': 'glsam',
        'depends_on_past': False,
        'start_date': datetime(2017, 6, 26),
        'provide_context': True,
        'retries': 100,
        'retry_delay': timedelta(seconds=30)
    }

    task_name = 'my_first_file_sensor_task'
    filepath = Variable.get("soucePath")
    filepattern = Variable.get("filePattern")
    archivepath = Variable.get("archivePath")

    dag = DAG(
        'task_name',
        default_args=default_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        max_active_runs=1,
        concurrency=1)

    sensor_task = OmegaFileSensor(
        task_id=task_name,
        filepath=filepath,
        filepattern=filepattern,
        poke_interval=3,
        dag=dag)


    def process_file(**context):
        file_to_process = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(
            key='file_name', task_ids=task_name)
        file = open(filepath + file_to_process, 'w')
        file.write('This is a test\n')
        file.write('of processing the file')
        file.close()


    proccess_task = PythonOperator(
        task_id='process_the_file', python_callable=process_file, dag=dag)

    archive_task = ArchiveFileOperator(
        task_id='archive_file',
        filepath=filepath,
        task_name=task_name,
        archivepath=archivepath,
        dag=dag)

    trigger = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id='trigger_dag_rerun', trigger_dag_id=task_name, dag=dag)

    sensor_task >> proccess_task >> archive_task >> trigger
```

And then this is my FileSenor

```
    import os
    import re

    from datetime import datetime
    from airflow.models import BaseOperator
    from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
    from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults
    from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator


    class ArchiveFileOperator(BaseOperator):
        @apply_defaults
        def __init__(self, filepath, archivepath, task_name, *args, **kwargs):
            super(ArchiveFileOperator, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.filepath = filepath
            self.archivepath = archivepath
            self.task_name = task_name

        def execute(self, context):
            file_name = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(self.task_name, key='file_name')
            os.rename(self.filepath + file_name, self.archivepath + file_name)


    class OmegaFileSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
        @apply_defaults
        def __init__(self, filepath, filepattern, *args, **kwargs):
            super(OmegaFileSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.filepath = filepath
            self.filepattern = filepattern

        def poke(self, context):
            full_path = self.filepath
            file_pattern = re.compile(self.filepattern)

            directory = os.listdir(full_path)

            for files in directory:
                if not re.match(file_pattern, files):
                    # do nothing
                else:
                    context['task_instance'].xcom_push('file_name', files)
                    return True
            return False

    class OmegaPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
        name = "omega_plugin"
        operators = [OmegaFileSensor, ArchiveFileOperator]
```

Comment: Do both the files live in ~/airflow/dag folder?

Comment: I placed the file sensor in a /airflow/plugins

Comment: This works! Thank you. If anyone needs help mounting the drive I used this article for CentOS (Amazon EC2-Instance): https://access.redhat.com/solutions/448263

Comment: Actually your logic is slightly wrong this code will not work unless you make some adjustments. In `OmegaFileSensor` you have to put the `return False` outside the `For Loop`. If you don't then it's going to only check the first file in the loop... Took me a while to realize why this was working when I had one file in the folder but not when I had multiple files in the folder. so just do `for files in directory: if not re.match(file_pattern, files): ~do nothing~ else: context['task_instance'].xcom_push('file_name', files) return True ~outside loop return False`

Comment: Thanks Kyle - as mentioned I'm a newb

Comment: @GlennSampson or Could anyone help to modify the code to do filesensor on remote host ?

Comment: Remote host as in different IP addresses? Have to mount to remote host on the Airflow machine... think Samba is an option off the top of my head

Comment: @GlennSampson I tried exactly what you have done but i got the following error: **Broken DAG: [/usr/local/airflow/dags/file_listen_sample.py] cannot import name 'OmegaFileSensor' from 'airflow.operators' (unknown location)**, Kindly can you help me?

Comment: The structure around creating a plugin has changed a little bit. Create a new question and link it here and I'll try and answer where there is more space