# Airflow Remote file sensor

Tags: airflow-scheduler, airflow

I am trying find if there is any files in the remote server match the provided pattern. Something as similar to the below solution
[Airflow File Sensor for sensing files on my local drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44325938/airflow-file-sensor-for-sensing-files-on-my-local-drive][1])

I used SSHOperator with bash command as below,

```
SSH_Bash = """
    echo 'poking for files...'
    ls /home/files/test.txt
    if [ $? -eq "0" ]; then    
    echo 'Found file'
    else
    echo 'failed to find'
    fi
    """

t1 = SSHOperator(
    ssh_conn_id='ssh_default',
    task_id='test_ssh_operator',
    command=SSH_Bash,
    dag=dag)
```

It works but doesnt look like an optimal solution. Could someone help me to get better solution than Bash script to sense the files in the remote server.

I tried the below sftp sensor ,

```
import os
import re

import logging
from paramiko import SFTP_NO_SUCH_FILE
from airflow.contrib.hooks.sftp_hook import SFTPHook
from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defaults


class SFTPSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, filepath,filepattern, sftp_conn_id='sftp_default', *args, **kwargs):
        super(SFTPSensor, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.filepattern = filepattern
        self.hook = SFTPHook(sftp_conn_id)

    def poke(self, context):
        full_path = self.filepath
        file_pattern = re.compile(self.filepattern)

        try:
            directory = os.listdir(self.hook.full_path)
            for files in directory:
                if not re.match(file_pattern, files):
                    self.log.info(files)
                    self.log.info(file_pattern)
                else:
                    context["task_instance"].xcom_push("file_name", files)
                    return True
            return False
        except IOError as e:
            if e.errno != SFTP_NO_SUCH_FILE:
                raise e
            return False

class SFTPSensorPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "sftp_sensor"
    sensors = [SFTPSensor]
```

But this always poke into local machine instead of remote machine. Could someone help me where i am making a mistake.

Comment: replaced the line from "directory = os.listdir(self.hook.full_path)" to "directory = self.hook.list_directory(full_path)" worked.

Comment: A question from here, then should I create a process called SFTPSensor() or BaseSensorOperator()?? Im not sure how to implement using the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced the line from

```
directory = os.listdir(self.hook.full_path)
```

to

```
directory = self.hook.list_directory(full_path)
```